# Dynamic zoom in Google Maps API v2 Android

Tags: android, google-maps, zooming

In Google Maps API v2, the method `animateCamera` is used to define the zoom level for viewing. For example,

```
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat1, lng1), 12));
```

Here, the zoom level is fixed to 12. How do I make sure that the zoom value fixed here, will allow the user to view source and destination points along the route **without manual zooming**.

I know using trial and error methods and some `if-else` conditions, the values can be determined. But is there a more sophisticated way of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use LatLngBounds like this:

```
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
builder.include(startPoint);
builder.include(endPoint);
LatLngBounds bound = builder.build();
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bound, 25), 1000, null);
```

startPoint and endPoint are LatLng objects.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Rajat is correct but you need to wait for map is loaded else you can get error "map size is 0".

```
googleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(this);
```

...

```
@Override
public void onMapLoaded() {
    if (googleMap != null) {
        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        builder.include(startPoint);
        builder.include(endPoint);
        LatLngBounds bound = builder.build();

        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bound, 40));
    }
}
```